# How to get the parent node of the current node while iterating over YAML::Node?

Tags: c++, yaml, yaml-cpp

I am building a tree structure while iterating over a `YAML::Node`. So far, i am able to build the tree when the hierarchy goes downwards. But if there is change in heirarchy i am not able to get the parent node.

```
batman:
  type: super hero
  entity: ""
  natural: yes
  attributes:
    powers:
      whip:
        x: ""
        y: ""
      batmobile:
        x: ""
        y: ""
```

Based on the above structure, how do i get the parent node of `batmobile`?
Assuming, i am iterating like this:

```
for (YAML::const_iterator it = node.begin(); it != node.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << it->first.as<std::string>() << std::endl; // prints batmobile
    
   // how to get the parent node of batmobile?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because in general, a YAML node does not have a single parent.

The content of a YAML file constitutes a directed graph, not a tree. For example, this YAML:

```yaml
- &a 123
- foo: *a
```

Defines a sequence of two items, the scalar node `123` and a mapping node containing a single key-value pair. That pair has the scalar `foo` as key and *the scalar node `123` as value* (the alias gets resolved by the parser). This means that the scalar node `123` is referenced from two places and thus does not have a single parent.

Another problem would be that within a pair `foo: bar`, asking for the parent node of `bar` would yield the mapping containing the pair, because the pair itself is not a node. But you probably also want to know the corresponding key.

The takeaway is that when descending into a YAML graph, you need to store the path you take somewhere if you want to backtrack.